# NoSuchFieldException: mFastScroller on android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, fastscroll

I am trying to implement custom **`FastScrollListener`** which is working fine on every platform except **Android Lollipop** where its crashing on the following line:

```
final Field fastScrollerField = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroller");
```

saying:

```
12-14 16:46:29.034: E/AndroidRuntime(29702): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mFastScroller
12-14 16:46:29.034: E/AndroidRuntime(29702): at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:886)
```

Can anyone guide me about the fix for Android Lollipop.

Comment: "which is working fine on every platform except Android Lollipop" -- and also except any device where the manufacturer or ROM modder changed `AbsListView` to no longer have `mFastScroller`, or to change its data type, etc. Do not rely upon internal implementation.

Comment: So, the fix is not to rely upon internal implementation then how can i do it?

Comment: Since `FastScrollListener` is not part of the Android SDK either, you simply don't do "it" at all. I have no idea what actual business problem you are trying to solve, I have no means of advising you on how to solve that business problem without resorting to unreliable techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution be comparing **`AbsListView`** of Lollipop with previous versions and found out the the keyword/name for getting declared feild is changed to **`mFastScroll`** from **`mFastScroller`**...